# Is it possible to achieve SSL connection when mail is received on port 25

Tags: delphi, email, ssl, smtp, indy

I have a `TIdSMTPServer` that is running on ports 25 and 465 and it's `OnConnect` event looks like this :

```
procedure TMainForm.SMTPServerConnect(AContext: TIdContext);
begin
  if (AContext.Connection.IOHandler is TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketBase) then begin
    TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketBase(AContext.Connection.IOHandler).PassThrough := False;
end;
```

Before activating `SMTPServer` this piece of code is executed :

```
with IdServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL1 do begin
  SSLOptions.CertFile := myCertFile;
  SSLOptions.RootCertFile := myRootCertFile;
  SSLOptions.KeyFile := myKeyFile;
end;
SMTPServer.IOHandler := IdServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL1;
```

Everything's fine when a client tries to connect to port 465 (using `implicit SSL`). But when another smtp server (for example `yahoo` or `gmail`) sends mail, it comes on port 25 and apparantely get's blocked in my `OnConnect` event. So I'm asking is it possible to issue something like `STARTTLS` and encrypt somehow with SSL the connection on port 25 or is there a way to tell the other side that I want to communicate on port 465 with SSL (using my certificates in both cases, the connection is always direct - without username/password authentication) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Indy 10, `PassThrough` is True by default.  You need to look at which Port number the client actually connected to before setting `PassThrough` to False, eg:

```
procedure TMainForm.SMTPServerConnect(AContext: TIdContext);
begin
  if (AContext.Connection.IOHandler is TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketBase) then
  begin
    if AContext.Binding.Port = 465 then begin
      TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketBase(AContext.Connection.IOHandler).PassThrough := False;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

`TIdHTTPServer` has an `OnQuerySSLPort` event that handles this detail for you.  That functionality has not been ported to other Indy server components yet, you have to do it manually.

You are acting as the *server*.  The *client* decides whether to initiate an SSL/TLS session or not, you cannot do that from the server side.  *IF* the client wants to use SSL/TLS on port 25, it will query your server's capabilities via a `EHLO` command and then send a `STARTTLS` command to your server if it reports `STARTTLS` in its `EHLO` reply.  `TIdSMTPServer` handles all of that for you, the only thing you have to do is assign an SSLIOHandler to the server and set the `TIdSMTPServer.UseTLS` property to either `utUseRequireTLS` or `utUseExplicitTLS`.

Comment: Is it possible to change the ``TIdSMTPServer.UseTLS`` property according to the port (``utUseImplicitTLS`` on port 465 and ``utUseExplicitTLS`` on port 25) or it has to be assigned once at start and remain the same the entire time the ``SMTPServer`` is active ?

Comment: And does the ``STARTTLS`` command (if issued by the client) can guarantee an encrypted SSL/TLS connection on port 25 ?

Comment: Yes, that is what `STARTTLS` is meant for. The client connects unencrypted, sends `STARTTLS` when ready, and if the server accepts it than they exchange an SSL/TLS handshake and everything is encrypted from that point onward.